# What is the new way of sending POST requests in batches for GA4?

Tags: node.js, post, backend, google-analytics-4

I am currently migrating our service from Universal Analytics to GA4. We deal with the data on the server side at present, using a custom nodejs package to anonymise user IP addresses and send data in batches. This means we can only send data after a specified timeframe and amount of different users in order to avoid any chance of identifying them.

Using wreck the original request looked as follows:
`wreck.request('post', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/batch', { agent: this._agent, payload: payload, timeout: 15000 }).then(() => { debug('Completed request to google analytics measurement protocol API') })`
However the '/batch' endpoint is no longer being continued for GA4. I cannot seem to find a new endpoint for this method of batching. I have been able to send a single event with the following request:

```
wreck
        .request('post', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?<api-secret>&measurement_id=<measurement-id>', {
          agent: this._agent,
          payload: {
            client_id: '1234',
            user_id: '4321',
            events: [
              {
                name: 'teest',
                params: {
                  page_view: 'True'
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          timeout: 0
        })
```

I have done comprehensive research, scouring the documentation but cannot seems to find the correct method or endpoint, has anyone else ben able to do this?
(p.s we will likely just end up doing the backend gtag method shown in Google's docs https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side but I just want to check if my attempt has been in vain)

I have tried a variety of endpoints found on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest but the realtime event never appears.